# Tkinter GUI Window Blank

Tags: python, tkinter

I decided to try and write a program that would calculate your body fat percentages based off measurements taken from a body fat tester. I created an excel spreadsheet a few years back for a buddy so he could calculate his clients body fat percentage. I thought it would be cool to create a program for him to use and it would also give me something to practice.

When I run the program it seems to run without any issues other than the fact that the Tkinter window comes up completely blank. Can anyone identify what I did wrong in my code?

Also if I get this working, is there anyway I can create an executable to give my buddy, or some way to have a desktop run a script to run the python code? He would be using a Mac, so with python already being installed I figure there is probably some way to run a terminal script but I don't know how that would be done.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, the code is below:

```
__author__ = 'jared'

import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import cmath

class BodyFatGUI:

 def __init__(self):

    #Create Main Window
    self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

    #Create Frames for wigets
    self.gender_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
    self.tricep_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
    self.chest_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
    self.abdominal_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
    self.suprailiac_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
    self.thigh_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
    self.button_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

    #Initialize Radio Buttons
    self.radio_var = tkinter.IntVar()
    self.radio_var.set(1)

    #Create gender widgets
    self.rb1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.gender_frame, text = 'Male', variable=self.radio_var, \
                               value = 1)

    self.rb2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.gender_frame, text = 'Female', variable=self.radio_var, \
                               value = 2)

    #Create age widget
    self.age_label = tkinter.Label(self.gender_frame, text='Age:')
    self.age_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.gender_frame, width='7')

    #Create skinfold widgets
    self.tricep_label = tkinter.Label(self.tricep_frame, text='Enter Tricep skinfold measurement:')
    self.tricep_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.tricep_frame, width=10)
    self.chest_label = tkinter.Label(self.chest_frame, text='Enter Chest skinfold measurement:')
    self.chest_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.chest_frame, width=10)
    self.abdominal_label = tkinter.Label(self.abdominal_frame, text = 'Enter Abdominal measurement:')
    self.abdominal_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.abdominal_frame, width=10)
    self.suprailiac_label = tkinter.Label(self.suprailiac_frame, text='Enter Suprailiac measurement:')
    self.suprailiac_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.suprailiac_frame, width=10)
    self.thigh_label = tkinter.Label(self.thigh_frame, text='Enter Thigh measurement:')
    self.thigh_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.thigh_frame, width=10)

    #create button frame
    self.calc_button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, text='Calculate', command=self.bodyfat)
    self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, text='Quit', command=self.main_window.destroy)

    #Pack the widgets
    self.rb1.pack(side='left')
    self.rb2.pack(side='left')
    self.age_label.pack(side='right')
    self.age_label.pack(side='right')
    self.tricep_label.pack(side='left')
    self.tricep_entry.pack(side='left')
    self.chest_label.pack(side='left')
    self.chest_entry.pack(side='left')
    self.abdominal_label.pack(side='left')
    self.abdominal_entry.pack(side='left')
    self.suprailiac_label.pack(side='left')
    self.suprailiac_entry.pack(side='left')
    self.thigh_label.pack(side='left')
    self.thigh_entry.pack(side='left')
    self.calc_button.pack(side='left')
    self.quit_button.pack(side='left')

    tkinter.mainloop()

 def bodyfat(self):
    #Get value entered from user

    tri = float(self.tricep_entry.get())
    chest = float(self.chest_entry.get())
    ab = float(self.abdominal_entry.get())
    sup = float(self.suprailiac_entry.get())
    thigh = float(self.thigh_entry.get())
    age = float(self.age_entry.get())

    sum = tri + chest + ab + sup + thigh

    if self.radio_var.get() is 'Male':

        bd = 1.1093800 - 0.008267*sum + 0.0000016*sum^2 - 0.0001392*age
        fat = ((4.570/bd) - 4.142)*100
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Results', 'Your calculated body fat percentage is: ' + str(fat))

    elif self.radio_var.get() is 'Female':

        bd = 1.0994921 - 0.0009929*sum + 0.0000023*sum^2 - 0.0001392*age
        fat = ((4.570/bd) - 4.142)*100
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Results', 'Your calculated body fat percentage is: ' + str(fat))

body_fat = BodyFatGUI()
```

Comment: did you run it in terminal/console/cmd.exe to see if there is no error message ?

Comment: to create executable for Mac you have to create it on Mac.

Comment: I ran it on PyCharm on a Mac.  The window popped up and was blank.  Is there a better way?

Comment: PyCharm should have `console` window which show errors and text printed by `print()` in script.

Comment: I check code and there was no error message. At this moment I don't know why tkinter window is empty.

Comment: simple method to work with problem: add many `print()` (with variables and/or text) and see what you get.

Comment: Ok.  I found the console.  Thanks for telling me about that.  I'm new to all of this, especially PyCharm so that's good to know.

I added print('hi') throughout the program and they appear until the bodyfat(self) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use `pack()` with all frames.

You need this to put frames in window:

```
self.gender_frame.pack()
self.tricep_frame.pack()
self.chest_frame.pack()
self.abdominal_frame.pack()
self.suprailiac_frame.pack()
self.thigh_frame.pack()
self.button_frame.pack()
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, that was it!

Comment: I've had to change a few lines now.  The age label is showing up, but there is no entry space.  

I noticed that this line of code:

    self.age_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.gender_frame, width='7')

Needs to have the '7' changed to 7, but it's still not showing up.  I added a self.age_frame.pack() line to your above recommendation.  Is there anything else I'm missing?

Thanks again for your help so far.

Edit:  I realized that I don't need to pack, and create an 'age_frame' since it is in the same frame as the 'gender_frame', is this correct?

Comment: Found it.  I had age_label twice, I needed an age_entry.

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the values of my radio buttons?  My if and elif functions aren't working.  I have a feeling it has to do with getting the selected values.

Comment: simple method to work with problem: use `print()` to see value returned by radiobutton

Comment: `self.radio_var.get()` doesn't return `Male` / `Female` - you set `value=1` / `value=2`

Comment: I figured out I needed a 1 or 2 instead of Male and Female right after I posted my comment.  I'm feeling really dumb today haha.  It's like  every time I ask a question I finally figure it out right after.

Comment: Now if I can just figure out this:

    

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/jared/PycharmProjects/BodyFat/Body Density.py", line 96, in bodyfat
    bd = 1.1093800 - 0.008267*float(sum) + 0.0000016*float(sum)^2 - 0.0001392*float(age)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'float'

Comment: the answer would be better if your pack statements used explicit options (side, fill, expand). The defaults are rarely good enough for a polished application.

Comment: I was unaware of those other packing options.  Looks like I need to read some documentation for tkinter.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I have everything working properly as I would like it for now.  Can anyone tell me how to create an executable from PyCharm?  Do I need to use something like pyinstaller?  Also is this possible while using Python 3?

Comment: PyCharm can't create executable. You need external program. For Mac it can be pyinstaller (or probably py2app). Read information on pyInstaller page. You can search answer on SO too.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I've been messing around with py2app all morning.  I'm able to get a "Density.app" file created in the "dist" folder, but every time I try to run it, it gives me an error and allows me to either terminate or open the terminal.  I've tried to build the app from the terminal numerous times and have got the same error every time.  Is this a common error?

Comment: what error ?  btw: if you have new problem then create new question on SO

Comment: When I try to access the .app file I get a popup window that said "Density Error".  Density is the name of the .app file.  There are two buttons, one says "Open Console" the other says "Terminate".  I'll post a new question with the terminal message on a new question.  I didn't want to start a new question and people get mad for starting new unnecessary threads.

Comment: people are mad when someone ask more than one question in one thread - SO is not traditional forum.